# How to create disc that installs Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, 13.10

I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 desktop -amd64 but it is an ISO file. Do I have to create a disc (make Bootable CD) to install new OS (Ubuntu 13.10)? I haven't done this before.

Comment: a dvd or a usb, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to burn the ISO file on the disc with a burning program. You can download it from [This site](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). After downloading follow this video for burning. [Burning Image Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_UZ4v2MQic). Please note you have to burn an "image", to make it bootable. Only an image(.ISO file) is bootable. So if you copy only the ISO file directly without burning on disc or usb(pendrive), your computer can't boot from it or your computer wont start installing Ubuntu.

Nearly, all burning programs, in Linux/Windows/Mac, have the option to burn an image. You have to select `Burn` or `Make bootable disc` button and not the copy-button.

If a correct image is burnt on the disc, you can boot it (please don't forget to indicate in the BIOS that you wish to boot from disc and not e. g. from a hard-disk).

If you didn't understand my last line then follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smL4hDBrN2A) after burning disc.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Burn the whole .ISO image to a disk. You can use imgburn, CDburnerXP, or whatever your preference is. You can also make a bootable USB with UNETbootin.